# How many points belong to a line in a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, finite-fields, solution-verification, finite-geometry

This is the continuation of this question: [What is the size of the set of lines in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of order $q$, where $q$ is a prime power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544120/what-is-the-size-of-the-set-of-lines-in-a-finite-field-mathbbf-q-of-order)

Now I need to show that exactly $q$ points belong to each line. Let $g \in \mathbb{F}_q, g \neq 0$. If $m,n,r,s,t \in [1,q]$ are integers, then we can represent $a,b,c$ as $a = g^m, b = g^n, c = g^r, x = g^s \text{ and } y = g^t$. Given $a,b,c$, we can then write the equation as $g^mg^s + g^ng^t = g^r$. Since $q$ is a prime power, I deduce that $m + s + n + t \equiv r \text{ mod } q$. Fixing a value of $s$ also fixes the value of $t$, so we have $q$ pairs $(x,y)=(g^s,g^t)$ for each line.

Please give your comment. Also my algebra is pretty rusty, so I think there should be a clearer way to say what I meant. If so please correct my answer.

Comment: A line has an equation that is either of the form $x=a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{F}_q$ or $y=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: You can't do this with an arbitrary $g \in \mathbb{F}_{q}$, unless it is a generator of your field there is no guarantee that other elements are powers of $g$. (And I don't know that you need to do this either).

Comment: Also, you are working over a finite field, where $q$ is a prime power; you can't associate this with the integers $\bmod{q}$ (even in the case where $q$ is prime, you are better off not thinking modular arithmetic and just think you are working in a field).

Answer (score 1):

Embed the affine plane $F_q \times F_q$ in the projective plane where $$(x,y) \mapsto (x:y:1)$$. Any line in the affine plane has the same number of points as any other line and the same is true in the projective plane. The points on the line $x=0$ in the affine plane are in 1-1 correspondence with the points $x=0$ in the projective plane except for the point (0:1:0). Any such point can be written uniquely as (0:b:1) where b is in $F_q$. There are $q$ such points.